# If A1 and A2 are two sub-sigma-algebras, can we say that E[E[X|A1]|A2]=E[E[X|A2]|A1]?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Take $(\Omega,F,P)$ where

$\Omega =\begin{Bmatrix}
 \omega_{1,1}&\omega_{1,2}  &\omega_{1,3} \\ 
 \omega_{2,1}&\omega_{2,2}  &\omega_{2,3} \\ 
 \omega_{3,1}&\omega_{3,2}  &\omega_{3,3} 
\end{Bmatrix}$ and $F=2^\Omega$.

Let $A_1$ a sub $\sigma$-field generated by:
$\left \{ \omega_{1,1},\omega_{1,2},\omega_{1,3} \right \},
\left \{ \omega_{2,1},\omega_{2,2},\omega_{2,3} \right \},
\left \{ \omega_{3,1},\omega_{3,2},\omega_{3,3} \right \}$

and $A_2$ a sub $\sigma$-field generated by:
$\left \{ \omega_{1,1} \right \},
\left \{ \omega_{1,2},\omega_{2,2},\omega_{2,1} \right \},
\left \{\omega_{1,3},\omega_{2,3},\omega_{3,1},\omega_{3,2},\omega_{3,3} \right \}$

If define a random variable $X$ as $X(\omega_{i,j})=i+j$, can we say that:

$E[E[X|A_1]|A_2]=E[E[X|A_2]|A_1]?$

Comment: No reason to expect this in general and actually the equality fails in general. Are you asking about the specific case?

Comment: No I'm asking for the general case

Comment: Then they are (obviously) different.

Comment: I've done like this: $E[S|Z=u]=2(2\frac {p_{11}}{p_{11}+p_{12}+p{13}})$, 

$E[S|Z=v]=(3\frac {p_{12}}{p_{12}+p_{22}+p_{21}}+3\frac {p_{21}}{p_{12}+p_{22}+p_{21}}+4\frac {p_{22}}{p_{12}+p_{22}+p_{21}})(3\frac {p_{12}}{p_{12}+p_{22}+p_{21}}+3\frac {p_{21}}{p_{12}+p_{22}+p_{21}}+4\frac {p_{22}}{p_{12}+p_{22}+p_{21}})$

same for $E[S|Z=v]$. I took the corrisponding value in $S$ of the $\omega$ in $Z$ for example: to $\omega_{11}$  in $S$ correspond $2\frac {p_{11}}{p_{11}+p_{12}+p{13}}$ is it wrong?

Comment: Not sure I am willing to check the details of your formulas... But, good news, here is a shortcut: if indeed $E(E(X\mid A_1)\mid A_2)=E(E(X\mid A_2)\mid A_1)$ then this random variable is simultaneously $A_1$-measurable and $A_2$-measurable. But the only random variables that are simultaneously $A_1$-measurable and $A_2$-measurable, are constant. Did you find that $E(E(X\mid A_1)\mid A_2)=E(E(X\mid A_2)\mid A_1)$ is constant?

Comment: no they aren't. I get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

I think that the best way of thinking about this simple yet overcomplicated (discrete) problem is as follows.

Consider two random variables $Y$ and $Z$ with the following definitions:

$$Y=\begin{cases}
a&\text{if}&\omega\in\{ \omega_{1,1},\omega_{1,2},\omega_{1,3} \}\\
b&\text{if}&\omega\in\{ \omega_{2,1},\omega_{2,2},\omega_{2,3} \}\\
c&\text{if}&\omega\in\{ \omega_{3,1},\omega_{3,2},\omega_{3,3} \},\end{cases}$$

$$Z=\begin{cases}
u&\text{if}&\omega\in\left \{ \omega_{1,1} \right \}\\
v&\text{if}&\omega\in\left \{ \omega_{1,2},\omega_{2,2},\omega_{2,1} \right \}\\
w&\text{if}&\omega\in\left \{\omega_{1,3},\omega_{2,3},\omega_{3,1},\omega_{3,2},\omega_{3,3} \right \}\end{cases}$$
where $a,b,c$ and $u,v,w$ are distinct reals.

With this notation, and because of the definition of the conditional expectation, for every $\omega\in\Omega$, $E[X\mid A_1],\ E[X\mid A_2] $ as functions of $\omega$ can be calculates as

$$E[X\mid A_1\ ](\omega)=E[X\mid Y=y\ ]$$
and $$E[X\mid A_2\ ](\omega)=E[X\mid Z=z\ ]$$
where $Y(\omega)=y$ and $Z(\omega)=z$.

By this the calculations are lead back to methods known from elementary probability theory.
Now, we have $S=E[\ X\mid A_1]$ and $R=E[\ X\mid A_2\ ]$ as functions of $\omega$. Then use the similar thread of thoughts when calculating

$$E[S\mid Z\ ]\text{ and } E[R\mid Y\ ].$$

**EDIT**

Let's get one step forward. A question: Who said that $P(\{\omega_{i,j}\})=\frac19$? In the general case, these probabilities are all different.
Let me use the following notation: $p_{ij}=P(\{\omega_{i,j}\}), \ i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Now, let's calculate $E[X\mid A_1]$ as a function of $\omega$. First, for $\omega_{1,1},\omega_{1,2}, \text{ and } \omega_{1,3}$.
For all of these lementary events $Y(\omega)=a$.

$$E[X\mid A_1](\omega_{1,1})=E[X\mid A_1](\omega_{1,2})=E[X\mid A_1](\omega_{1,3})=$$
$$=E[X\mid Y=a]=$$
$$=2P(X=2\mid Y=a)+3P(X=3\mid Y=a)+4P(X=4\mid Y=a)=$$
$$=2\frac{p_{11}}{p_{11}+p_{12}+p_{13}}+3\frac{p_{12}}{p_{11}+p_{12}+p_{13}}+4\frac{p_{1,3}}{p_{11}+p_{12}+p_{13}}.$$

The same way

$$E[X\mid A_1](\omega_{2,1})=E[X\mid A_1](\omega_{2,2})=E[X\mid A_1](\omega_{2,3})=$$
$$=E[X\mid Y=b]=$$
$$=2P(X=2\mid Y=b)+3P(X=3\mid Y=b)+4P(X=4\mid Y=b)=$$
$$=3\frac{p_{21}}{p_{21}+p_{22}+p_{23}}+4\frac{p_{22}}{p_{21}+p_{22}+p_{23}}+5\frac{p_{2,3}}{p_{21}+p_{22}+p_{23}}.$$

and

$$E[X\mid A_1](\omega_{3,1})=E[X\mid A_1](\omega_{3,2})=E[X\mid A_1](\omega_{3,3})=$$
$$=E[X\mid Y=c]=$$
$$=2P(X=2\mid Y=c)+3P(X=3\mid Y=c)+4P(X=4\mid Y=c)=$$
$$=4\frac{p_{31}}{p_{31}+p_{32}+p_{33}}+5\frac{p_{3,2}}{p_{31}+p_{32}+p_{33}}+6\frac{p_{33}}{p_{31}+p_{32}+p_{33}}.$$

If $p_{ij}$ are $\frac19$ then $E[X\mid A_1]$ as a random variable (a function of $\omega$ can be pictured easily over:

$$\Omega=\begin{Bmatrix}
 \omega_{1,1}&\omega_{1,2}  &\omega_{1,3} \\ 
 \omega_{2,1}&\omega_{2,2}  &\omega_{2,3} \\ 
 \omega_{3,1}&\omega_{3,2}  &\omega_{3,3} 
\end{Bmatrix}$$

like this

$$\begin{Bmatrix}
 3&3  &3 \\ 
 4&4  &4 \\ 
 5&5 &5
\end{Bmatrix}.$$

Could you do $E[X\mid A_2]$ now?

Comment: thank you for the answer. How can I use the fact that $X(\omega_{i,j})=i+j$?

Comment: You will need the conditional probabilities: $P(X=2\mid Y=a),P(X=3\mid Y=a),P(X=4\mid Y=a)$. Can you follow?

Comment: please help me a little bit more if you can, it's two days I'm thinking but still I can't solve this

Comment: OK but give me some time.

Comment: I've done it one step ahead...

Comment: thank you so much! I'm trying to calculate $E[X|A_2]$

Comment: I've done like this: $E[X|Z=u]=2\frac {p_{11}}{p_{11}}$=2, 
$E[X|Z=v]=3\frac {p_{12}}{p_{12}+p_{22}+p_{21}}+3\frac {p_{21}}{p_{12}+p_{22}+p_{21}}+4\frac {p_{22}}{p_{12}+p_{22}+p_{21}}$,$E[X|Z=w]=4\frac {p_{13}}{p_{13}+p_{23}+p_{31}+p_{32}+p_{33}}+5\frac {p_{23}}{p_{13}+p_{23}+p_{31}+p_{32}+p_{33}}+4\frac {p_{31}}{p_{13}+p_{23}+p_{31}+p_{32}+p_{33}}+5\frac {p_{32}}{p_{13}+p_{23}+p_{31}+p_{32}+p_{33}}+6\frac {p_{33}}{p_{13}+p_{23}+p_{31}+p_{32}+p_{33}}$    is it correct?

Comment: That seems to be correct. **** I think that the general case is two complicated though. So, I would encourage you to use $\frac19$ from now on. But be specific regarding the function nature of the conditional probability. Draw the little figure. **** Then do $E[E[X\mid A_1]\mid A_2]$ and the other thing. With $\frac19$ you can easily see if the two are the same (or not). **** Then check if you have the right to use $\frac19$. If not, since you are already smart :) do the same in general.

Comment: The answer is yes they are equal :) correct?

Comment: Don't count on me. I did not do the whole problem. /  Lazyboy.

Comment: I can tell you that is yes, I've done the general case. Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: "I can tell you that is yes, I've done the general case" **OUCH!** No, they are not equal in general.